# Trouble reversing a .pyc file back to its source code

Tags: python-3.x, decompiling, pyc, uncompyle6

I have an EXE compiled using cx_Freeze, and the answer here pointed me to decompyle3 after getting the .pyc file:
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26257/how-to-reverse-engineer-cx-freeze-exes

I tried that but got an error `Unknown magic number 3495`. My Python version is 3.8.18, and I'm also getting:

```
I don't know about Python version '3.8.18' yet.
xdis might need to be informed about version '3.8.18'
```

Based on this, I modified the header of the .pyc file:
https://book.hacktricks.xyz/generic-methodologies-and-resources/basic-forensic-methodology/specific-software-file-type-tricks/.pyc

Now, uncompyle6 says `KeyError: '3.8.18'` and decompyle3 says `Unknown magic number 21773`

I'm struggling to find resources on this topic, and I'm unfamiliar with decompiling pyc files.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: A Python decompiler has to explicitly support each version of Python; lying to it (by editing the header) is unlikely to help, as the bytecode format *actually changes* every time the magic number changes.  However, the magic numbers you're quoting don't seem to correspond to the Python versions you mention, so I'm not sure what's actually going on here.  Magic 3495 is Python 3.11b4, for example.  And 21773 isn't a valid magic number at all, that looks like you tried to set it to 3413 (Python 3.8b4) but got the bytes backwards.

Comment: @jasonharper yeah so the .pyc file I'm trying to reverse is probably compiled using 3.11. However, my installed Python version is only 3.8. So, should I just install 3.11? Do those two tools support reversing 3.11?

Comment: It's the decompiler that needs to explicitly support the Python version being decompiled - the Python version you're running it under doesn't need to match.  (There's no particular reason the decompiler has to be written in Python at all!)